# Get the minimum value in the chart rendered for flot.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Is it possible to get the lowest value in the chart itself assuming that the data is dynamic?Take a look at this example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a_miguel6687/ze76e/1/).

```
$(function () {
    var d1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5)
        d1.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);


    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ d1]);
});
```

How can I get the lowest value in this line chart?

Update: It seems my earlier example didn't quite make sense please take a look at this link: https://abtw.alliancebernstein.com.tw/APAC/TW/Funds/American-Income.htm?ShareClassId=60006908 make sure to turn off Flash plugin so that Flotchart will render. Now looking at the area chart I want to get the lowest value base on the chart rendered. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

If you save your `plot` object like so

```
var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ d1]);
```

you can get the minimum value from it with

```
var minimum = plot.getData()[0].yaxis.datamin;
```

The same is possible for maximum value (`datamax`), for the xaxis and for other data series (the index behind `getData()`).

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/Sf5Yr/

Simply keep a `lowest` variable, and check throughout the `for-loop` to see if the value lower, if so, replace the current lowest value with it.

```
$(function () {
var d1 = [];
//Assuming you're always starting at zero
var lowest = Math.sin(0);
for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5) {
    d1.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
    if (Math.sin(i) < lowest) {
        lowest = Math.sin(i);
    }
}
alert(lowest)
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [d1]);
});
```